# Omniauth linkedin gem no longer pulls full profile on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api, omniauth

I am currently trying to grab the full profile of a user in order to access her past three positions. The API was working exactly how I wanted to and I can't find in my old commits exactly what went wrong.  Here is my initializer for linkedin-omniauth.

Here is my initializer:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do    
  provider :linkedin,
           ENV['LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY'],
           ENV['LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET'],
           :scope => 'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_contactinfo',
           :fields => ["id", "email-address", "first-name", "last-name", "headline", "industry", "picture-url", "public-profile-url", "location"]
end
```

I've been playing around for hours with the fields, but not sure what to put.  Here are the 2 resources I've been using:

- https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#fullprofile
- https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#positions

I'm using the gems omniauth and omniauth-linkedin, Ruby on Rails 4.1.4 and ruby 2.1.2.

Comment: I'm not super familiar, but do you need to pull `positions` in the fields list?

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `positions` to the fields array:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do    
  provider :linkedin,
           ENV['LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY'],
           ENV['LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET'],
           :scope => 'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_contactinfo',
           :fields => ["id", "email-address", "first-name", "last-name", "headline", "industry", "picture-url", "public-profile-url", "location", "positions"]
end
```